# How to scroll div onclick to left or right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<div class="main_container">
<div class="first_div">
<div class="first_container_box">
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2 id="heading">Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div class="second_div">
<div class="second_container_box">
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#heading").click(function(){
       $('.main_container').animate({left:'+100px'}, 1000);
    });
});​
```

Here is the [JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfnan8p/)

Here what I want is when I click on h2 with id 'heading', 'main_container' div should scroll towards the 'second_div'.

Can anyone please tell me how to do it??

Comment: Is this what you were after = [http://jsfiddle.net/fdfnan8p/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfnan8p/3/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#heading").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('body').animate({scrollLeft:'+=500'}, 500);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfnan8p/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like below [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfnan8p/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#heading").click(function(){
          $('body').animate({scrollLeft:'500%'}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your container is set to 200% wide, you need to animate by -100%, like below:

```
$("#heading").click(function() {
    $('.main_container').animate({marginLeft:'-100%'}, 500);
});
```

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdfnan8p/10/)